# clickable link in a Json object for a popup

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

I need to say I have very small background in ruby and json anyways for a school project we are putting tweets on a mapbox map,and I need to make the link clickables so here is the code that should do it:

```
<% if @tweets.any? %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>

<%      linked = tweet.text.gsub( %r{https://[^\s<]+} ) do |url|
        "<a href='#{url}' class='text_link' target = 'blank'>#{url}</a>"
        end         
    %>

    features.push({
        type:'Feature',
        geometry:{
            type:'Point',
            coordinates:[<%=tweet.geo.coordinates[1]%>, <%=tweet.geo.coordinates[0]%>]
        },
        properties:{
            title:"",
            description: '<p><%= linked.to_json %><br><%= image_tag(tweet.media[0]["media_url_https"], :size => tweet.media[0]["sizes"]["thumb"], class: "img-responsive") if(tweet.media.present?) %></p>',
            "marker-symbol": "myMarker"


        }
    });
<% end %>
```

this seems working but when clicked it goes

```
No route matches [GET] "/'https://(myurl)'"
```

and the url appears as follows:

```
localhost:3000/'https://(myurl)'
```

i tried html_safe but it doesnt work!

Comment: What exactly does `url` itself print (you can substitute the domain if needed)? Is it a valid URL? Or does it contain other characters (such as a prefixed slash or quote)?

Comment: JSON is just a string. Do you mean an object literal? If you parse JSON, it is no longer JSON.

Comment: ahh I found the solutions, apparently all those single quotes are not needed, i just changed with:    
`"<a href=#{url} class=text_link target = _blank>#{url}</a>"`
and now everything is working fine